# Change sensible-browser

Tags: default-programs

Some of my apps use the script `sensible-browser` to open web pages. This script opens `/etc/alternatives/gnome-www-browser` or `/etc/alternatives/x-www-browser`. On my machine, these two are symbolic links to Google Chrome (which I rarely use). I want to use Firefox instead, so I made them into symbolic links to `firefox`.
Now if I use `sensible-browser`, Firefox is used. However, for some inexplicable reason the symbolic links are regularly reverted back to point to Google Chrome!

What is the correct way to change `sensible-browser`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change `gnome-www-browser` to point to say `/usr/bin/firefox`

You can do

```
sudo update-alternatives --set gnome-www-browser /usr/bin/firefox
```

Similarly you can do the same to the other one also i think.

**Edit:**

Or..

You can do

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
```

which gives a list of all the browsers to choose from, from which you can select one of them.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using snap managed firefox using `update-alternatives` won't work, but you can open firefox and go to it's settings (`about:preferences`) and click "Set default" button.

https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/firefox-snap-cannot-be-set-as-default-browser/26636/2